# Check which element has been clicked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use an 'if' statement to determine which element was clicked.

Basically I am trying to code something along the lines of:

```
if (the element clicked is '#news_gallery li .over') {
    var article = $('#news-article .news-article');
} else if (the element clicked is '#work_gallery li .over') {
    var article = $('#work-article .work-article');
} else if (the element clicked is '#search-item li') {
    var article = $('#search-item .search-article');
};
```

What is the proper jQuery syntax for this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you setting up your click handler?

Comment: @vision: "along the lines of", e.g. it's pseudo-code

Comment: Tons of these snippet codes are present on internet. First search then ask.

Comment: @MarcB Right, I skipped that words and stared into the code block which was totally different at that time. Now of course my comment is obsolete.

Comment: Why don't you just simple use a global variable? what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use this, I think I can get your idea.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/h722g/1/

```
$('body').click(function(e) {

    var target = $(e.target), article;

    if (target.is('#news_gallery li .over')) {
       article = $('#news-article .news-article');
    } else if (target.is('#work_gallery li .over')) {
       article = $('#work-article .work-article');
    } else if (target.is('#search-item li')) {
       article = $('#search-item .search-article');
    }

    if (article) {
       // Do Something
    }
});​
```

Comment: "var target = $(e.target), article;  "
What does ", article" do here?

Comment: @masteroleary that's just a variable declaration because the OP needs to evaluate a `CSS` class from the clicked item (`target`) in order to pick another one which is stored in the `article` variable.

Comment: @OscarJara so its initializing article as undefined? The real question is: how have I not come across this in 15 years???

Answer (score 21):

So you are doing this a bit backwards.  Typically you'd do something like this:

```
​<div class='article'>
  Article 1
</div>
<div class='article'>
  Article 2
</div>
<div class='article'>
  Article 3
</div>​
```

And then in your jQuery:

```
$('.article').click(function(){
    article = $(this).text(); //$(this) is what you clicked!
    });​
```

When I see things like `#search-item .search-article`, `#search-item .search-article`, and `#search-item .search-article` I sense you are overspecifying your CSS which makes writing concise jQuery very difficult.  This should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: Just a small tip for anyone else who reads this answer in the future: Use `console.log($(this).get())` in case you're not sure whether `$(this)` is selecting what you expect. This will print a list of selected elements for you in the console log.

Answer (score 11):

[Answer from vpiTriumph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707283/2162226) lays out the details nicely.
Here's a small handy variation for when there are unique element ids for the data set you want to access:

```
$('.news-article').click(function(event){    
    var id = event.target.id;
    console.log('id = ' + id); 
});
```

Comment: Nice, event usage!  Note, you forgot to pass in event to function, i.e., `function(event)`, getting "event is undefined" otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Another option can be to utilize the `tagName` property of the `e.target`. It doesn't apply exactly here, but let's say I have a class of something that's applied to either a `DIV` or an `A` tag, and I want to see if that class was clicked, and determine whether it was the `DIV` or the `A` that was clicked. I can do something like:

```
$('.example-class').click(function(e){
  if ((e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()) == 'a') {
    console.log('You clicked an A element.');
  } else { // DIV, we assume in this example
    console.log('You clicked a DIV element.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The basis of jQuery is the ability to find items in the DOM through selectors, and then checking properties on those selectors.  Read up on Selectors here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

However, it would make more sense to create event handlers for the click events for the different functionality that should occur based on what is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this useful for you.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if ($('#news_gallery').on('clicked')) {
        var article = $('#news-article .news-article');
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#news_gallery li .over").click(function() {
    article = $("#news-article .news-article");
});
```

Comment: Unfortuantely setting up 3 different functions won't work. I am basically using the variable for a kind of 'lightbox' gallery, so the variable needs to reside within a single click function that animates the entire 'lightbox'.