# How can I exactly identify the element which an eventlistener has fired from?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a slide show in a modal window! First I click on one of the 12 images on the website...then the            modal window opens which contains a window with a slideshow... the picture (img) which I clicked should be seen (as a background-image) as the first picture in the slideshow. 
The pictures on the webpage are in a div with the id pic_cnt

In the div of the modal slideshow window (id modal_window) there are 12 divs (for each picture) with the class modal_pic! Every div with this class has the background-image in the same order as the img on the webpage but with opacity 0.

I added an eventlistener to each img on the page which opens the modal window! How can I connect the clicked img with the same background-image? When an img is clicked a class (.current) to the same background-image in the modal window should be added to change the opacity to 1. Please help!

```js
let modal = document.getElementById('modal');
let clickedPic = document.querySelectorAll('#pic_cnt img');
let modalPic = document.querySelectorAll('#modal_window div');

for (let i = 0; i < clickedPic.length; i++) {
  clickedPic[i].addEventListener('click', openModal)
}

function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, .8);
}

#modal_window {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 55%;
  width: 55%;
}

.modal_pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  ;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.current {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="pictures">
  <div id="pic_cnt">
    <div><img src="Images/18.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/5.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/6.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/14.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/16.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/19.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/9.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/17.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/3.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/15.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/7.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/10.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="modal">
    <div id="modal_window">
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event listener, `this` is the element you clicked on. You can get the parent DIV, and then get its index in the `pic_cnt` DIV, then use that index to find the corresponding DIV in the modal.

```js
let modal = document.getElementById('modal');
let clickedPic = document.querySelectorAll('#pic_cnt img');
let modalPic = document.querySelectorAll('#modal_window div');

for (let i = 0; i < clickedPic.length; i++) {
  clickedPic[i].addEventListener('click', openModal)
}

function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  let index = Array.from(this.parentElement.parentElement.children).indexOf(this.parentElement);
  console.log(index);
  for (let i = 0; i < modalPic.length; i++) {
    modalPic[i].style.opacity = i == index ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

```css
#modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, .8);
}

#modal_window {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 55%;
  width: 55%;
}

.modal_pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  ;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.current {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="pictures">
  <div id="pic_cnt">
    <div><img src="Images/18.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/5.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/6.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/14.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/16.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/19.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/9.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/17.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/3.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/15.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/7.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/10.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="modal">
    <div id="modal_window">
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 1</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 2</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 3</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 4</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 5</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 6</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 7</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 8</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 9</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 10</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 11</div>
      <div class="modal_pic">Pic 12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

> FYI: when you run example it takes couple seconds for me to event get
>   fired

I got rid of most of the divs and kept only one, sine you only need one div and you can replace the inside content of it on every click depending on image.

I used

> $(e.target)

which gives you the item that has been clicked(***Read***  [Check which element has been clicked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706903/check-which-element-has-been-clicked-with-jquery)). Once you have access to that element you can do the rest. I then pass that target element to your openmodal() function and update the div content.

comment if anything is unclear.

```js
 
  let modal_div = document.getElementById('modal');
$('img').click(function(e) {
  console.log(e)
  var modal = $('.modal_pic');
  var target = $(e.target);
  openModal(target);
}
 );
 

function openModal( target) {
 
 $('.modal_pic').append(target[0])
  modal_div.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, .8);
}

#modal_window {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 55%;
  width: 55%;
}

.modal_pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  ;
  position: absolute;
   
}

.current {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script><section id="pictures">
  <div id="pic_cnt">
    <div><img height="50px" src="http://i.imgur.com/sRgTlGR.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img height="50px" src="http://i.imgur.com/WJXklif.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img height="50px" src="http://i.imgur.com/sRgTlGR.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img height="50px" src="http://i.imgur.com/WJXklif.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/16.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/19.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/9.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/17.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/3.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/15.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/7.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div><img src="Images/10.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="modal">
    <div id="modal_window">
       
      <div class="modal_pic"></div>
       
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```